# How can you view details of a failed uninstall of a managed package?

Tags: managed-package, beta-managed-package, uninstall

I am trying to uninstall a first-generation managed package beta version, and am receiving an Uninstall Status "Uninstall Failed." Is there any way to view more details of why this is failing? Is there an object representing these uninstall jobs that can be queried?

[image]

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you should have gotten an email with details. I don't know if it's logged elsewhere.

Comment: Is this in a sandbox or production?  We found the production uninstall didn't provide any details of failure, but in sandbox it gave us more information about the failure

Comment: @sfdcfox this is the correct answer thank you. The email of the user was not as expected. I changed the user's email and successfully received an error email with details of the error. In this particular case I had a permission set being the criteria for membership in an Experience. It's odd, because normally when you still have references to components, it recognizes it in the validation, and let's you know before starting the uninstall.

Comment: @NickCook it is a developer edition, so production.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.distribution_uninstalling_packages.htm&type=5) document:

- You can’t uninstall a package whenever a component not included in the uninstall references any component in the package. For example:

  - When an installed package includes any component on a standard object that another component references, Salesforce prevents you from uninstalling the package. An example is a package that includes a custom user field with a workflow rule that gets triggered when the value of that field is a specific value. Uninstalling the package would prevent your workflow from working.
  - When you’ve installed two unrelated packages that each include a custom object and one custom object component references a component in the other, you can’t uninstall the package. An example is if you install an expense report app that includes a custom user field and create a validation rule on another installed custom object that references that custom user field. However, uninstalling the expense report app prevents the validation rule from working.
  - When an installed folder contains components you added after installation, Salesforce prevents you from uninstalling the package.
  - When an installed letterhead is used for an email template you added after installation, Salesforce prevents you from uninstalling the package.
    When an installed package includes a custom field that’s referenced by Einstein Prediction Builder or Case Classification, Salesforce prevents you from uninstalling the package. Before uninstalling the package, edit the prediction in Prediction Builder or Case Classification so that it no longer references the custom field.
- You can’t uninstall a package that removes all active business and person account record types. Activate at least one other business or person account record type, and try again.
- You can’t uninstall a package if a background job is updating a field added by the package, such as an update to a roll-up summary field. Wait until the background job finishes, and try again.

Comment: Thanks Tushar, even though this doesn't directly answer my question, that document is very good information. I hadn't thought about possible background jobs.